# Can't attach debugger to Quasar main process

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-debugger, quasar-framework

I'm building an electron application using [Quasar Framework](https://quasar.dev/).
I'm having some trouble debugging the main process of Electron of it with VS Code.

When I start my app with `quasar dev -m electron` I can see the debugger is listening:

`Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/d2fa14ad-cc55-42e6-a81b-a7c71e6e5650`

Then I created a `launch.json` config with the following:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach",
    "port": 5858
}
```

When I click to attach I can see the message `Debugger attached` but all my breakpoints set on files of the main process get greyed out with the message `Breakpoint set but not yet bound`:

[image: screen shot of greyed out breakpoint]

Answer (score 1):

This is how to debug Quasar Electron App Main Process with VS Code or WebStorm.

Quasar doesn't run electron-main.js from the source code. It creates a webpacked js file in .quasar/electron folder with no correlation to src file. That's why you can't set a breakpoint in your src file.

The file is .quasar/electron folder is nothing but a webpack of your electron project. Therefore, you need to extend webpack configuration (`extendWebpack`) and add source maps to let you attach the debugger. Here is the config needed:

```
cfg.devtool = ctx.dev ? "#cheap-module-eval-source-map" : "#source-map"
```

Here is a more complete example (only above line is needed):

```
    electron: {
      bundler: "builder", // 'builder' or 'packager'

      extendWebpack(cfg) {
        cfg.devtool = ctx.dev ? "#cheap-module-eval-source-map" : "#source-map"
      },
   }
```

Run this in command line to specify ports:

```
quasar dev --debug -m electron -- --remote-debugging-port=9222 --inspect-brk=5858
```

9222 is for chrome UI
5858 is for node main process (it is default if you haven't set it)

Attach your debuggers to the opened ports and it should be good to go. You can use --inspect-brk=5858 to keep the app stop at first JavaScript line of the main process and then attach your debugger. More information about these switches is available here:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process

I made this work with WebStorm, and I am sure same works with VS Code.

[image: WebStorm Config to debug electron apps]

You can use port 9222 to debug Chrome UI. In VS Code, you can change `launch.json` to attach to it:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to url with files served from ./out",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "url": "<url of the open browser tab to connect to>",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/out"
        }
    ]
}
```

(https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug)

If you have a lot of Node modules, you may want to exclude them from Webpack build when debugging. Here is configuration for excluding node modules (https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals)

```
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals")


    electron: {
  bundler: "builder", // 'builder' or 'packager'
  extendWebpack(cfg) {
    // do something with Electron main process Webpack cfg
    // chainWebpack also available besides this extendWebpack
    cfg.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../node_modules")) // lerna modules
    cfg.devtool = ctx.dev ? "#cheap-module-eval-source-map" : "#source-map"

    // this is externals for electron webpack main chain
    cfg.externals = [
      nodeExternals({
        modulesDir: "../../node_modules",
      }),
    ] // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
  },
```

}

Note that "../../" was needed for lerna setup. If you have node modules next to the project, you need to exclude it from that dir ( `modulesDir: "node_modules"`).

Comment: Remove the `-t mat`. That's for Material Theme which was a pre-v1.0 command-line option. No longer relevant with v1.+

Comment: @Hawkeye64 Removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a type of "launch" for "node" working with this:

```json
        {
            "name": "Debug Main Process",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src-electron/electron-main.js",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
            "windows": {
              "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
            },
            "args" : ["."],
            "outputCapture": "std"
        }
```

When you select this for debug in vscode and start a debug session (F5), you will be asked for the process to attach too.

[image]

and, you can see the breakpoints in `electron-main.js` are good:

[image]

Comment: Did the directory path change?  Your version:

    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src-electron/electron-main.js"

Doesn't match the actual file location which is:

    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src-electron/main-process/electron-main.js"

But when I try this correction, I get "Exception, cannot use import statement outside a module". So neither path is working for me.